# What is the reference for ´System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure´?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

Using [Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 2 extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d), it generates model classes with the following imports:

```
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
```

**What reference do I need to include into my project using Visual Studio 2010?**

Currently, I have the following *References*:

- log4net
- System.configuration
- System.Core
- System.Data
- System.Data.Entity
- System.Web
- System.Web.Mvc
- System.XML

And in the *Add Reference* dialog I have the following:

[image: Add Reference Dialog]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Don't add EF lib via "Add reference" dialog (it's old version)
You need to add NuGet package "EntityFramework" of latest version.

Comment: That did the job! I removed the old version added via "Add reference" diagog then I added the NuGet package "EntityFramework" (version 5). Thanks!

Comment: This applies to Version 6.0 as well

Comment: But I do not find this DLL "system.data.entity.design" in "EntityFramework" nuget package , can you help me?

Comment: What do you need this DLL for?