# error CS0433: The type 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedAttribute' exists

Tags: teamcity

I use .net version 2012 and MS build 4.0 subveriosn Ankh SVN repository with team city for continous integration. When I run the solution it thrown  eror as below

(26, 10): error CS0433: The type 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedAttribute' exists in both 'c:\BuildAgent\work\98284cd997678fbf\IC.Icrmas.UI\bin\EntityFramework.dll' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll'

I carefully see the versions of dlls which referred in the project and in referencing locations both are identical. In my build agent I have .Net frame work 4.5 installed. Please suggest me how can I resolve and go ahead on this?

Comment: bit late, but [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/02a22079-e3c4-4d90-9dbf-c73f59c409fd/build-errors-after-changing-an-mvc-internet-project-from-net40-to-net45) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13810017/what-is-the-reference-for-system-data-entity-infrastructure) might help for anyone else searching.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the Entity Framework from the Nuget Manager